# Google SEO search keyword. get to know how each word is converting

Tags: seo

Is there any way to pull the SEO keywords from Google and merge it with my data and understand the conversion rate of each keyword?

I want to try and focus on promoting only relevant keywords.

Not PPC, I'm talking about only SEO.

Thanks

Comment: When you mean "from Google" do you mean from Google Search Console?

Answer (score 1):

It is for me not possible to answer this question without a bit of advertising. Take [KeywordHero](https://keyword-hero.com) - with it you'll get organic keywords into GA (instead of usual not provided). Setup additionally extended ecommerce tracking and you are done - you get ecommerce / conversion data and organic keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Google has limited the ability of users to see keywords from organic search, but it does give you some data. The more organic search traffic your website has, the more useful it will be.

Requirements:

1. Google Search Console set up and linked to Analytics.
2. Conversion goals configured in Analytics.

You can then, under the Search Console section of Google Analytics, view Search Queries with conversions.

If you have specific information about the outcome of conversion actions, you can link this data into Google Analytics, but you must have some means of associating this data with existing users within Analytics (which isn't easy).

Here's Google's page on linking Search Console with Analytics, which should help you get started.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1308617?hl=en